# How to force sleep in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-10, bios, windows-registry, sleep, windows-11

I have a Windows 11 laptop and it won't go to sleep. The fan continues to run and various lights stay on. What should I do?

Apparently, some people on Windows 10 are having the same problem.

For what it's worth, the laptop is a Dell X17 and there is no way to enforce S3 sleep in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

In `Powershell` run `reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0` (there is no newline anywhere in this command) then restart your computer.

For more information, see [this discussion on Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-modern-standby-in-windows-10-may/db950560-33da-4a90-8340-b1f181f5efe6?auth=1&page=2).

See also a [Dell community post](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/How-to-disable-modern-standby-in-Windows-21H1/td-p/7996308) noting that this works.

I tried this on a Dell Alienware X17 running Windows 11 Version `21H2` and it works.

---

Outdated information below:

Previously, it was possible to open `Registry` and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power` and set `CsEnabled=0`, but this hack was no longer possible after the `21H1` Windows update.

Answer (score 0):

The very good answer from Benjamin Wang should work for most, but here is an update that covers both old and more recent Windows 10 & 11 versions out there, including the latest as of 2024.

Registry entries:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power]
"CsEnabled"=dword:00000000
"EnforceDisconnectedStandby"=dword:00000001
"PlatformAoAcOverride"=dword:00000000
```

PowerShell commands for the settings above to take effect:

```
POWERCFG /SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e SUB_NONE CONNECTIVITYINSTANDBY 0
POWERCFG /SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e SUB_NONE CONNECTIVITYINSTANDBY 0
```

Reference:
https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_solutions_int/esuprt_solutions_int_solutions_resources/client-mobile-solution-resources_white-papers45_en-us.pdf