# Windows 11 Forced sleep mode?

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate

I had problems with sleep mode/fan noise and found the only thing that worked was the answer here https://superuser.com/a/1697199/1890608
however it seems that this is actually for hibernate mode and although it solves the noise problem it takes 30's to boot up unlike sleep mode which is instant.

I wondered therefore if there was a similar command that is specifically for sleep mode?

Ok so Its a Lenovo LOQ with Windows 11 home edition, the problem was setting closing the lid to activate sleep mode, which it does but the fans kept starting up, this happens whether activating manually or by closing the lid, all drivers/BIOS are up to date, i've tried everthing but the only thing that worked was the answer above, but as I said it seems to activate hibernate only as opposed to sleep mode.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1830067/edit) your post and explain exactly what are the symptoms of the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem with a different Lenovo. It's  a faulty BIOS, they took a year or so to update. The best you can do is open a ticket with Lenovo. // What you can try is to first enable sleep, and only then close the lid

Comment: I did have a ticket open with Lenovo but couldnt bare to erase everthing that had taken so long to setup, i'm ok(ish) with how things are now I'd just prefer not to have to wait for the boot up every time  i open the lid.

Comment: In Sleep mode, the CPU is in a very low power state (though still draining power, if on battery) and *should not* need the cooling fan. If the fan runs during Sleep, then there is likely an issue such as defective BIOS or temperature sensing. This needs fixing by Lenovo.